# after using glowing effects mobile devices showing different css design than windows

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

my desktop screenshot is this - i hover on the card in the middle and its inner image gets showed up-
[image]

but in iphone and ipad, when i hover on the same card, i get this - [image]

I am using github repository. before using glowing effects, it was working the same in both platforms.
My glowing parts css-

```
.container-fluid .swiper-container .swiper-wrapper .swiper-slide .flip-card .flip-card-front:before{
  position:absolute;
  top: -2px;
  left: -2px;
  bottom: -2px;
  right: -2px;

  content:'';
  border-radius:15px;
  border: 3px;
  background: #fff;
  z-index: -1;

}
.container-fluid .swiper-container .swiper-wrapper .swiper-slide .flip-card .flip-card-front:after{
  position:absolute;
  top: -2px;
  left: -2px;
  bottom: -2px;
  right: -2px;

  content:'';
  border-radius:15px;
  border: 3px;
  background: #fff;
  z-index: -2;
  filter: blur(40px);

}
.container-fluid .swiper-container .swiper-wrapper .swiper-slide .flip-card .flip-card-front:nth-child(2n):before,
.container-fluid .swiper-container .swiper-wrapper .swiper-slide .flip-card .flip-card-front:nth-child(2n):after{
  background: linear-gradient(90deg, rgba(2,0,36,1) 0%, rgba(9,9,121,1) 35%, rgba(0,212,255,1) 100%);

}
.container-fluid .swiper-container .swiper-wrapper .swiper-slide .flip-card .flip-card-front:nth-child(2n+1):before,
.container-fluid .swiper-container .swiper-wrapper .swiper-slide .flip-card .flip-card-front:nth-child(2n+1):after{
  background: linear-gradient(90deg, rgba(2,0,36,1) 0%, rgba(40,47,50,1) 35%, rgba(0,212,255,1) 100%);

}
```

My html code for a single card -

```
<div class="swiper-slide">
            <div class="flip-card">
              <div class="flip-card-inner">
                <div class="flip-card-front">
                  <img src="images/bd_back.jpg" alt="Avatar" style="border-radius:15px; border: 3px solid #1c87c9 ;width:300px;height:300px;">
                </div>
              <div class="flip-card-back">
            <!--<img src="images/tamim1.png" alt="Avatar" style="width:300px; border-radius:15px; border: 3px solid #1c87c9;">
          <div class="overlay ctr"><a href="index.html"><button type="button" class="btn btn-outline-light">Let's Go!</button></a></div>-->
          <div class="wrapper">
            <img src="images/fake_m.png" class="pichone" style="border-radius:15px; border: 3px solid #1c87c9;" />
            <img src="images/mash1.png" class="shamne" style="border-radius:15px; border: 3px solid #1c87c9;" />
            <div class="overlay ctr"><a href="index.html"><button type="button" class="btn btn-outline-light">Let's Go!</button></a></div>
           </div>

        </div>

      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Comment: What github repo? And do you load it before or after your CSS? Another thing: can `.flip-card-front` be found in other locations than `.container-fluid .swiper-container .swiper-wrapper .swiper-slide .flip-card`? Because if not, you don't need to fully qualify the CSS like you did. Simply `.flip-card-front { ... }` and  `.flip-card-front:nth-child(2n):before { ... }` etc, will suffice. Less code, less maintenance...

Comment: github link - https://yaad88.github.io/emblembangladesh.github.io/tamim.html, this page. 
and thanks for the suggstion man. Also i would like to point out that i tried it in android devices, css was loaded correctly. Seems like its only the apple products issue